# How to make a wheel of self compiled version of PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to make a wheel package of self-compiled version of pyqt5. After downloading it from source (PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz) I've added qmediastreamscontrols.sip as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281010/qmediaplayer-how-to-play-video-with-multiple-audio) discussion.

How can I get a wheel of this with qt libraries in it.

Comment: Not only must you add the .sip which is a trivial task but you have to compile the source code so that the modified .so is generated.

Comment: On the other hand, I recommend you wait a bit because pyqt5 already added everything you need (more classes) and in a next release you will no longer have to make the patch, see https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt5/ChangeLog-5.14.3.dev2005051533